# How to format Excel worksheet?

Tags: c#, windows, excel, c#-4.0

Am using Microsoft.ACE.OleDb to write data to excel. I want to format the worksheet by using Microsoft.ACE.OleDb only? My requirement is i dont want to use 3rd party libraries like Microsoft.InterOp and EPPlus. How can i do this?

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working (exception/error message) ?

Comment: Haven't you already asked about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970988/how-to-do-formatting-in-excel-by-using-c/)?

Comment: the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) must read `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. `Microsoft.ACE.OleDb` allows you to operate data, not to format cells and text

If you don't want to use Interop.Excel, you should look at [Late binding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902)

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to create a real Excel worksheet with formatting is using Aspose.Cells for .NET.

There also is ExcelPackagePlus on CodePlex, which is opensource, but it has a bug that prevents reading or writing workseets when your text contains a www/mail-Link that is invalid, e.g. a password that contains an @ sign, with excel incorrectly interpreting this as a link.

There is also carlosag.excelwriter, but it doesn't really create an excel file, it creates an XML file that can be read and displayed by excel. 
Excel 2010 however issues a warning, "Not a valid excel file", that may potentially scare off users.

I would not recommend using ACE.OleDb, you will run into 32/64 bit issues, as the ACE drivers are already on life-support and deprecated and thus not available on 64 bit windows (matters if you have 64 bit excel as well).

For the same reason, I would not use Interop.Excel.